# Wrap two nodes with values greater than 0 with a div

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to convert the following xml with xslt

```
<item>0</item>
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
<item>0</item>
<item>6</item>
```

into the following html

```
<div>
  <i>1</i> 
  <i>2</i>
</div>

<div>
  <i>3</i> 
  <i>6</i>
</div>
```

In other words to remove nodes with 0 value and to wrap every 2 nodes with one div

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site helps fix problems, it's not for "give me the codez".

Comment: I wrote my problem.I can do both tasks separately, but not together. I don't think this will help you somehow.

Comment: I mean, show us the xslt you've tried to use so far that's not working. If you don't have even that, then we're not going to do your work/job for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"> 

<xsl:param name="value" select="0"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[not(. = $value)][position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="group">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::item[not(. = $value)][1]"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then with the input being

```
<root>
<item>0</item>
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
<item>0</item>
<item>6</item>
</root>
```

you get the result

```
<root>
   <div>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
   </div>
   <div>
      <item>3</item>
      <item>6</item>
   </div>
</root>
```

If you also want to transform `item` to `i` elements simply add the template

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <i>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </i>
</xsl:template>
```

in the stylesheet.