# Re-using nested XSL templates

Tags: xslt

I am trying to re-use a XSL template, and place other templates within this template, multiple times.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<xsl:template name="wrapper">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="template1"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="template2"></xsl:template>
```

So, now i want to apply both template 1 and template 2 inside template 'wrapper', something like this (I know this isn't the right code, but the idea is there):

```
<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <!--code here-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="template2">
    <xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <!--code here-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help on this would be grealty appreciated.

Comment: This is not how it works. What are you trying to do? Please supply some input XML and according desired output.

Comment: I can see the edges of what you're trying to achieve but, as @Tomalak says, unless we have some examples to help us understand we can't really answer in any useful fashion

Comment: You are aware of `<xsl:call-template>` and the fact you can “nest” those, i.e., invoke call-template inside a named template, yes?

Comment: @Rinux, without a sample xml its difficult to come up with a solution (that you are expecting), all we could diagnose with your statements is answered by Hon' Tomalak. Provide an XML, it will be an easy bite :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, The XSL file was part of a huge (existing) framework, with lots and lots of XML and XSL. At the time of asking it was actually my first encounter with XSL, and I totally misunderstood the proper use of XSL. However, i think your answer came closest to what I asked. Thank you (all) for your time=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is syntactically illegal to nest a template definition into another**.

As per the W3C XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) specification, an `xsl:template` must be a child of the top element `xsl:stylesheet`.

This means that all templates in a stylesheet module must be siblings.

**The way to invoke a** *named template* **is to use the `xsl:call-template` instruction like this**:

```
<xsl:call-template name="someTemplateName">
 <!-- Possibly place one or more `xsl:with-param` elements here -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

**However, beaware that**:

**It is a good style and more in the spirit of XSLT to use unnamed templates (that have a `match` attribute) and to select the best matching template with an `xsl:apply-templates` instruction**.

Most of the answers to SO XSLT questions demonstrate the use of `xsl:apply-templates`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, now i want to apply both template 1 and template 2 inside template 'wrapper',

If I take this literally:

```
<xsl:template name="wrapper">
  <xsl:call-template name="template1" />
  <xsl:call-template name="template2" />
</xsl:template>
```

But I have a strong gut feeling that you're somehow shooting yourself in the foot here.

Comment: I am doing stuff with the xml within template 1 and 2. However, the wrapper has nothing to do with the xml. The idea is this:

`<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <!--code here-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="template2">
    <xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <!--code here-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>`

I am very new at XSL, and I am starting to believe that I am using it in the wrong way. However, if something like this would be possible, it would come in very handy.

Comment: @Rinux: You're still not telling me what you are trying to do. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are trying to do X and think Y might work, so you ask about Y but never tell what X is. Please give me actual XML to work with.

Comment: Allright; you're right. here's my X: I have some content that's being rendered with PHP/XML and XLST. I want this content to be rendered in the 'wrapper', which is a table, containing the images for shadows. Why not use CSS? Internet Explorer. However, I did some extensive search and i think I might have found a solution with pure CSS. And - as I said - I think I was using XLST in the wrong way. Next time I'll think in the X, not in the Y. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rinux: You *still* did not give me some actual XML to work with.

Comment: @Rinux: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/9022980/254252 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/9022119/254252 for good ways of asking this kind of thing. Also have a (deep) look at http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - seriously, it does help.

Comment: Sorry everyone;) I was completely misunderstanding the essential of XLST. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Rinux This is kinda not satisfying, but there you go. *PS. For the sake of the question (and for the fact that you're an XSLT beginner) I still think you might learn a thing or two if you post your XML.*